# Jinja dictionary value not showing

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a Flask App where I create a form with RadioFields as choices, and I also pass a `param2` dict through to the jinja client-side.

I successfully render the individual Radiofields as subfields but I can not seem to render the text for the dict value that accompanies the key.

The label of the radiofield is also the key of the dict in `param2`, and I'm trying to get it's value printed next to the `subfield.label` text.

**param2 looks like this:**

```
param2{'Text Label1': 'completed', 'Text Label2': 'busy'}
```

When I print {{ param2 }} on the page, I get the dict as it should be.

```
{'Text Label1': 'completed', 'Text Label2': 'busy'}
```

**Here is how I print the subfield and call the dict.**

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
    {% for subfield in form.display %}
    <tr>  
        <td> {{ form.csrf_token }} </td>
        <td> {{ subfield }} {{ subfield.label }} </td>
        <td> {{ param2[subfield.label] }} </td> 
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

**When the code renders, the param2's `<td> </td>` is empty:**

```
<tr>  
    <td> <input id="display-0" name="display" type="radio" value="5"> <label for="display-0">Text Label1</label> </td>
    <td>  </td> 
</tr>
```

**Output I'm trying to get**

<>  Text Label1  completed

<>  Text Label2  busy

Comment: Could you post examples of another parameters like `form.display`? For now in looks like `subfield.label` value is `<label for="display-0">Text Label1</label>` and it is not in `param2` dictionary.

Comment: sorry for taking so long. the label is in param2, I will post an example in the question. This is what it looks like when i print it on the page `{'Text Label1': 'completed', 'Text Label2': 'busy'}`

Comment: No, you have already printed `param2` value. Your result in the last <td> tag depends of `subfield.label` value. I think it is not `Text label1` as you expect but `<label for="display-0">Text Label1</label>` instead. You need to print `form.display` to find out the last column value.

Comment: Ok I understand. So how would I get the value of label from the HTML tag returned in `subfield.label`?    `<label for="display-0">Text Label1</label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

As @sergey-shubin said, the `subfield.label` property of the `form` is an HTML construct, 
meaning:

if you call `{% subfield.label %}`

then you will get `<label for="display-0">Text Label1</label>`. <-- HTML Construct

**Solution:**

You can extract the label itself from the construct by calling the `text` method `subfield.label.text` which yields `Text Label1` from the HTML construct.

[Answer found here](http://nullege.com/codes/search/wtforms.widgets.HTMLString)